# Accidently removed Windows 7 while trying to install Hackintosh

Tags: windows-7

When I was trying to install SL on my computer, I got to the part where I need to format the partition I made (which is separate from my Windows 7 Partition) to an OS X format.  I did this, and now when I try to boot to Windows 7 it says "Missing Operating System" though in OS X when I look in my C drive, all the files are clearly there.  Is there some way to recover this using the "Disk Utility" app, or anything else for that matter?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably only killed your MBR.  You can [restore the boot sector](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851681.aspx) using the windows install CD.

Comment: So do my files exist or not, even if they show up in the OS X finder?

Comment: If you see them in Finder they likely still exist.  In this case, fixing the MBR will allow you to boot to that partition again.

Comment: How can I fix the MBR without actually installing another OS?

Answer (score 0):

You probably did kill your MBR.  What bootloader are you using (Chameleon/iboot)? Also what guide are you following?
And yes you can fix your mbr by booting up to the windows 7 disc and clicking on "Repair your computer." [Instructions are here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair_4.htm), though you will probably make your mac install unbootable doing that.  Once you have windows 7 booting again, I would recommend trying to reinstall your  mac install and boot loader.

Comment: I was using Hackos, which is similar to iBoot, and I never was able to even install it.  I could only run utility programs from the disk.  I'll probably give it up this time, and just go with Macbuntu

Comment: It can't find any disk images to repair...

Comment: What guide were you using for your install?  Did you make sure to format the drive as a GUID drive and not MBR? This is how you should format it (Steps 1 and 2): [Dual boot Windows 7 and SL](http://tonymacx86.blogspot.com/2009/11/dual-boot-windows-7-and-os-x-snow.html)
At this point I would backup all your Windows files (through finder) and reinstall Windows 7. If your drive is not formatted like in the link above, you should backup everything and repartition your drive just like that guide.  This was the only way I was able to fix my Hackintosh when I was in your same bind.